# Getting address of rvalue in C99

Tags: c, gcc, c99, undefined-behavior

The following code compiles and works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(void* x)
{
    printf("%d", *(int*)x);
}

int main()
{
    print(&((struct { int x, y; }){ .x = 1, .y = 2 })); //outputs 1
    return 0;
}
```

Why compiler allows me to get address of rvalue? Is this defined behaviour?

http://ideone.com/iMwNVr

Comment: These are designated initializers which were introduced in C99, aren't they? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: Yep. GCC uses `x : 1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(struct { int x, y; }){ .x = 1, .y = 2 }` is a compound literal, and:

> #### C99 §6.5.2.5 Compound literals
>
> If the type name specifies an array of unknown size, the size is determined by the initializer list as specified in §6.7.8, and the type of the compound literal is that of the completed array type. Otherwise (when the type name specifies an object type), the type of the compound literal is that specified by the type name. In either case, **the result is an lvalue.**